# Instance of Linq class without connecting it to database

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, submit, conflict

Is there a way to create an instance of a linq class without it being included in the next Submit?

like this:

```
 Customer customer = new Customer();
 Context.SubmitChanges(); // customer is not added.
```

I get an error back saying that some values can not be null because constraints in the database, even if i dont have `Context.Contacts.InsertOnSubmit(contact);` between the lines. I thought that as long as i did not call the `InsertOnSubmit` I could use the Customer class generated by the dbml as a storage or anything else... Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong, or am I trying to break the rules here?

Comment: What you're doing is ok (using an entity object without saving it).  Could you post the actual error message?  And can you post any more of your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suspect that you have attached that object to another in some sort of assignment. It isn't exactly obvious, but that actually causes it to be included in the submit.

Comment: this was exactly what i made that was casing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the entity `Customer` as you want in your code but you have to consider if you assign it to another entity that uses `customer` or added to the `datacontext` you have and then called `SubmitChanges` , you will get this error as long as there are null values in your `customer` entity that not allowing null in the actual `customer` database table